# Activity Launch Mode with GCM Message

Tags: android

I faced a problem in android activity launch.

I am using GCM for push notification. Push notification has the ID.
When I receive notification I launch an activity which has a button when we click button we open an activity which has the detail against that ID.

Every thing working fine the problem on when two push message arrived.

I am able to get detail activity for only one message.

New message replace old running activity.
can any one help me to get detail for both message.

we have A,B,C activities.

Before Message we are on A. when message arrive B acitvity resume, from B we open C and than come back to A. now on B when again message arrive we want already running B and also open new B activity . both B have their separate C activity for detail.
can any one help to solve this

Answer (score 0):

So the problem might not relate to GCM at all, but perhaps on activity life cycle? You could look at launch modes to reuse existing activities in the stack:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

You should be able to declare the wanted behaviour in your manifest, or programmatically in your startActivity call with intent flags.